# Trouble selecting exact string between two characters SQLite3

Tags: string, sqlite, grouping

I want to create a list that counts number of email providers regardless of what country code is specified. ie, ex@gmail.com and ex@gmail.uk would both be grouped under gmail.

I am using the substr() function, but I can't select between the '@' and the '.' .

this is my code:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@')) AS 'Provider', COUNT(email) 
AS 'Count' 
    FROM Customer
    GROUP BY Provider
    ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

and my ouput currently looks like this:

```
Provider    Count
----------  ----------
@gmail.com  8
@hotmail.c  4
@shaw.ca    3
@aol.com    2
@surfeu.de  2
@uol.com.b  2
@yahoo.com  2
@yahoo.de   2
@yahoo.fr   2
@apple.at   1
@apple.be   1
@apple.com  1
@apple.fi   1
@apple.fr   1
@apple.hu   1
@apple.ie   1
@comcast.c  1
@embraer.c  1
@google.co  1
@jetbrains  1
@jubii.dk   1
@microsoft  1
@rediff.co  1
@riotur.go  1
@rogers.ca  1
@sapo.pt    1
@woodstock  1
@wp.pl      1
@yachoo.ca  1
@yahoo.ar   1
@yahoo.au   1
@yahoo.ca   1
@yahoo.cl   1
@yahoo.es   1
@yahoo.in   1
@yahoo.it   1
@yahoo.nl   1
@yahoo.no   1
@yahoo.pt   1
@yahoo.se   1
@yahoo.uk   1
```

Hopefully this gives you an idea and you can help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that `INSTR()` can't be offset by some amount; it will return the first occurrence of whatever you specify.  Hence, this is a problem, because you want to find the position of the first dot in the domain portion of the email address, but occurring *after* the at symbol.

In the query below, the unit of work is the following substring:

```
SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1)
```

This finds everything to the right of the at symbol.  Then, we use `INSTR()` on this to substring everything between the at symbol and the first dot.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),
           1,
           INSTR(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1), '.') - 1) AS Provider,
    COUNT(*) AS p_count
FROM Customer
GROUP BY
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),
           1,
           INSTR(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1), '.') - 1)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I can't offer you a live demo for SQLite, but in MySQL the `INSTR()` and `SUBSTR()` functions behave almost the same, and the above query seems to be completely portable.

If you want the query to appear a bit cleaner, you could wrap in a subquery to avoid repeating the ugly substring operation in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    t.Provider, COUNT(*) AS p_count
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUBSTR(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),
               1,
               INSTR(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1), '.') - 1) AS Provider,
    FROM Customer
) t
GROUP BY t.Provider
```

## Demo